# Yoast SEO: title tags are repeating my website name and slogan

Tags: seo, plugin-wp-seo-yoast

I am using the Yoast SEO plugin and I am finding that on my site it is repeating the website title and blog tagline twice. For example, it looks something like this in my browser tab:

Example.com | This is my tagline Example.com This is my tagline

I have implemented, just as Yoast says, the following code in my header.php:

```
<title><?php wp_title(''); ?></title>
```

Would it also be helpful for me to provide an export of my SEO plugin settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`wp_title()` is filterable so there could be another plugin or most likely your theme already adding a filter.  Have tried checking the force rewrite in the plugin options?  If that doesn't work you need to hunt down what else is adding the filter and remove it. If it's your theme look in functions.php for

`add_filter('wp_title', 'some_function_name' );`

Remove that line.

Comment: Yes, it was a snippet of code in my Starkers Theme causing the issue! I removed it. Thank you!